# Using Handlebar Templates in a Rails Engine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, handlebars.js

I'm trying to link up my handlebar assets(specifically a tree) in my rails engine in vendor/assets/javascript/templates/tree_name/_tree.hbs. I've successfully added other js file by initializing it in my engine.rb and running `rake assets:precompile`

```
initializer "engine_name.assets.precompile" do |app|
  app.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js property.js.coffee /templates)
end
```

Unfortunately, the handlebar templates aren't loading at all. I was wondering if anyone had another approach to loading these assets in an engine.

Comment: Are you using a gem to make Rails aware of `.hbs` files?

Comment: @muistooshort yup, I've got handlebars_assets installed.

Comment: Are you sure that `/templates` shouldn't be `templates`?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried them both and neither worked.